# Windows serial port reading is extremely slow compared to theory

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I am trying to make a simple program which sends 9 bytes of data over a COM port to a microcontroller, then waits for 11 bytes of data from the microcontroller. The entire process has to occur within 500µs, which is feasible at 115200 bauds (edit: sorry, feasible at 500kbauds, but this test is done at 115.2k).

However, I have measured the duration of an iteration (which yields correct results) using QueryPerformanceCounter and the total duration (dominated by reading) varies wildly between 4 and 6ms instead of 1.7ms - even at 500kbauds the duration stays around 4-5ms! How is this possible? How can I remedy to this?

I have tested ALL libraries I could find out there, they all yield similar results (or do not work at all when reading), but here is an example with Boost on MSVC. I am all ears if you have tested anything on your side which works.

PC:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp> 
#include <boost/asio.hpp> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try 
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io;
        boost::asio::serial_port arduino(io, "COM3");
        arduino.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200));

        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
        LARGE_INTEGER start;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

        //Send first set of duty cycles first
        char dc[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        boost::asio::write(arduino, boost::asio::buffer(dc, 9));
        char buf[11] = { 0 };
        boost::asio::read(arduino, boost::asio::buffer(buf, 11));

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
            printf("%d ", buf[i]);
        }

        LARGE_INTEGER end;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
        double interval = static_cast<double>(end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart * 1000000; // in seconds
        printf("(%f us)\n", interval);

    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error& e)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Output:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 -1 7 (6234.500000 us)
*/
```

Arduino:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define BAUDRATE 115200
#define N_BYTES_IN 9
#define PERIOD_US 1200

unsigned int ssiDummyVal = 2047;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUDRATE);
  while(Serial.available()); //Flush buffer (need to reset the arduino after connection and before transmission of bytes).
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); //Dummy output
}

unsigned long t;

void loop() {
  t = micros();
  
  while(Serial.available() < N_BYTES_IN); //Wait for duty cycles

  //Receive duty cycles
  unsigned char dc[N_BYTES_IN];
  for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < N_BYTES_IN ; ++i)
  {
    dc[i] = Serial.read();
    analogWrite(LED_BUILTIN, dc[i]);
  }

  //Send dummy current values
  for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < N_BYTES_IN ; ++i)
  {
    unsigned int val = float(analogRead(A0))/1023*255;
    Serial.write(i);
  }

  //Bit-bang SSI interface TODO

  //Finally send SSI value as 2 bytes
  unsigned char ssiValLSB = ssiDummyVal & 255;
  unsigned char ssiValMSB = (ssiDummyVal >> 8) & 255;
  Serial.write(ssiValLSB); //LSByte first
  Serial.write(ssiValMSB); //MSByte second

  unsigned long dt;
  //Only for the 10 first samples to avoid clogging the screen
  static unsigned int sample = 0;
  while((dt = abs(micros()-t)) < PERIOD_US) //Estimate how much time margin we have
  {
    if(sample < 10) { 
      //Serial.write(int(float(dt)/PERIOD_US*255)); //Gives the fraction of the period_us used to do the iteration
    }
  }
  sample++;
}
```

Comment: `while(Serial.available() < N_BYTES_IN);` should you not sleep in there, to make sure all the CPU doesn't go to just this while loop ?

Comment: This is the microcontroller's code you are referring to, it has nothing to do in the meantime.

Comment: The while seem like a busy wait. If it performs atomic memory operations or locking inside it might both overuse some CPU power and might result in other issues. Which why it should have a short wait inside. Aside from that - no idea why you want to use a COM port - it is an outdated port with poor support from some OS.

Comment: Because it is the simplest and fastest-to-implement kind of communication between the PC and the microcontroller I selected for the job.

Comment: I have made other tests with minimal code and the results confirm there is something wrong with all libraries I have tested. See above, it does not seem to be (only) a latency issue. I'm stuck, and this is for work... No one can help me at work. Any ideas? I can't believe something so basic does not work like it should and it is not written anywhere.

Comment: I have updated my post with yet another failure using Boost on MSVC and some more information.

Comment: The busy-wait is poiuntless. `read()` will block anyway. You're just smoking the CPU.

Comment: Why don't you check the actual line usage status with an analytical device (line monitor/protocol analyzer/oscilloscope) that allows you to know the detailed time? How about grasping the situation at the most physical layer level and then gradually changing the scope of investigation?

Comment: Maybe these threads are helpful. [Maximum baud rate between RPi+arduino](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=659538.0), [Maximum Baudrate of Native USB Port ? Increase Communication Speed ?](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=401154.0), [Arduino Due - Serial speed?](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=132811.0)

Comment: Seems like you expect high-performance (i.e. low latency) realtime OS (i.e. consistent/predictable latency) results from a general-purpose OS for a desktop.  I've seem similar results for Linux, but there are tricks for tweaking the Linux kernel to significantly reduce read latency.

Comment: *"I have measured the duration of an iteration ... and the total duration (dominated by reading) ..."* --  *"Reading"* seems to *"dominate"* primarily because the "write" request returns as soon as the data is queued up (but not yet output).  Your *"measurement"* then lumps the actual time to perform the transmission as part of the "read" time.  *"the duration stays around 4-5ms! How is this possible?"* -- It's called system overhead and the scheduling delays of a non-realtime OS.

Comment: Buffering the input solved my problem (increased the Arduino's serial buffers, then filled them up at the beginning of the program and at every tick of the sample timer on the PC I read the values from the input buffer and send yet another command on the buffer stack). However I'm still interested in the details of this overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Your math is wrong.

200 serial symbols (110 out, 90 back, because your 8-N-1 configuration uses 10 timeslices per byte... 1 start, 8 data, 1 stop) at 115200 baud will take over 1.7 milliseconds just for the data transfer.  That allows no time for interrupt handling and thread scheduling or for the microcontroller to receive its message and compose a response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - you are right that I was blind to the fact the baudrate was in bps and not in Bps. The problem still stands though, because I could live with 1.7ms at 115kbauds (I'll bump that up to 500k, it already works in RealTerm) but not with the 5-6ms I'm getting with all the libraries. The Arduino itself finishes the entire iteration in 1.1ms at 500k but I get the same duration with 500kbauds. Something's up!

Comment: I have updated my post with yet another failure using Boost on MSVC and some more information.